# Use MongoDB with python2

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I'm using python2 for a project. It is old I know, but it is better for my project in terms of flexibility.
I need to connect a MongoDB to it, but when I try the connection it gives to me an error:

```
File "/Users/user/Desktop/cartella senza nome 2/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 366, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e))
pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: connection closed
```

This is my script:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import dns

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://dbmacems:<passowrd>@cluster0-shard-00-00.sulle.mongodb.net:27017/scan?w=majority&authSource=admin")
db = client.test
```

Maybe is why I'm using python2?
So there is a fix to this or can I use similar "web" databases like MongoDB for python2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is missing the `tls` URI option. Carefully copy it from  the Atlas UI.

Comment: I can't find a method four use this option, can you fix my code with that?
I also recently tried this:

`cluster0-shard-00-00.sulle.mongodb.net:27017/scan?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-rc8hx2-shard-0&authSource=admin`.

The traceback mention the ssl / tls option but I can't found how to set that...

`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command {'ismaster': 1} failed: no SNI name sent, make sure using a MongoDB 3.4+ driver/shell.`

I need help

Comment: Use the most recent driver version.